# Sequnce vs TextChoice vs IntegerChoices in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Which method is preferable for determining the choices in the `choices` argument when defining the model field in Django?

Suppose I have a some model:

```py
class Balance(models.Model):
    reason = models.CharField(choices=...) # or models.IntegerField
    ...
```

Sequnce:

```py
REFILL = 1
CASHBACK = 2
SUBSCRIPTION = 3
ORDER = 4
Reason = (
    (REFILL, "Refill"),
    (CASHBACK, "Cashback"),
    (SUBSCRIPTION, "Subscription"),
    (ORDER, "Order"),
)
```

TextChoices:

```py
class Reason(TextChoices):
    REFILL = "refill", "Refill"
    CASHBACK = "cashback", "Cashback"
    SUBSCRIPTION = "subscription", "Subscription"
    ORDER = "order", "Order"
```

IntegerChoices:

```py
class Reason(IntegerChoices):
    REFILL = 1, "Refill"
    CASHBACK = 2, "Cashback"
    SUBSCRIPTION = 3, "Subscription"
    ORDER = 4, "Order"
```

Django documentation does not give preference to any one method. Just showing different ways. I often see examples with a sequence, but what's wrong with using TextChoices or IntegerChoices? In what situations is it better to use these classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but what's wrong with using `TextChoices` or `IntegerChoices`?

**Nothing**, in fact there is an advantage of using these: these will check that the same key does not occur multiple times. Indeed, if you define an `IntegerChoice`:

```
class Reason(IntegerChoices):
    REFILL = 1, "Refill"
    CASHBACK = 2, "Cashback"
    SUBSCRIPTION = 3, "Subscription"
    ORDER = 2, "Order"
```

it will raise an error saying that the value for `ORDER` has occurred already for `CASHBACK`, so it prevents making mistakes.

But the `IntegerChoices` and `TextChoices` are in fact only a utility function: if you use `TextChoices.choices`, it will construct a list of 2-tuples, so it is merely a thin wrapper.

The reason the documentation probably uses tuples and/or lists is that this was originally the way to define choices before `TextChoices` and `IntegerChoices` were introduced, and furthermore allow easily to inline the definition (i.e. `my_field = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[('a', 'active'), ('p', 'passive')])`), the `IntegerChoices` and `TextChoices` are thus more something that can be used to generate the list of choices automatically, and these the `Reason` will be an `Enum` as well, hence you can pass `Reason` objects that (more or less) guarantee that it is one of the existing options.